# Show all activities for Cases I am following

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am a novice Dynamics 365 CRM (online) administrator for a small business that offers Technical Support to our Customers.  We want to transition from our old ticket system to Dynamics 365's Cases and I have been working to customize it for our needs.  One area I am having difficulty with is Activities related to Cases I am following.

Using United Interface, is there a way I can display any Activities that other users have added to the Cases I am following?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into creating a Dashboard with a [Timeline](https://crmtipoftheday.com/1214/add-whats-new-to-unified-interface/) component.

And here's some additional info about the Timeline control:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/customer-service-hub-user-guide-timeline-overview

Comment: Close, I'm trying to add a "section" on a Dashboard to show all Activities for any Cases I'm following.  Even if those Activities were added by other users.  I can't find where to add Timelines to a Dashboard and then "filter" by Cases I Follow